# Integrating existing hibernate functionality into Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

My coworker and I inherited a jar that contains a few domain classes and a spring context that creates a session factory for Hibernate. This is a redacted version of the context file's hibernate pieces:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.ours.OurDataSource">
    <constructor-arg value="dml-rdbms-data-source.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="searchSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="searchSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>a.b.c.DefGhe</value>
            <value>a.b.c.Xyz</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <bean class="our.com.ManagedPropertiesFactory" factory-method="getProperties">
            <constructor-arg value="hibernate.properties" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I changed the sessionFactory bean to be called searchSessionFactory in order to avoid a name collision with the built-in grails hibernate session factory. That doesn't seem to help. I still get this error when trying to save a Grails-generated domain class:

```
Unknown entity: x.y.z.DomClass; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: x.y.z.DomClass
```

Has anyone run into a situation where they had to integrate existing hibernate functionality like this into Grails?

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be resolved for us now, so here's what we did to resolve it:

1. Removed all of that content from resources.xml
2. Used a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext strategically to load the spring context in the grails code that needed it.

Part of the problem is that the defined `dataSource`, `sessionFactory` and `transactionManager` beans were conflicting with Grails' conventions. Grails generates them from the data provided in DataSource.groovy. It was picking up on these definitions and things were not working because that was being overridden.